# Different behaviour using unidirectional or bidirectional relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, eclipselink

I want to persist a mail entity which has some resources (inline or attachment). First I related them as a bidirectional relation:

```
@Entity
public class Mail extends BaseEntity {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mail", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<MailResource> resource;

    private String receiver;
    private String subject;
    private String body;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date queued;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date sent;

    public Mail(String receiver, String subject, String body) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.body = body;
        this.queued = new Date();
        this.resource = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addResource(String name, MailResourceType type, byte[] content) {
        resource.add(new MailResource(this, name, type, content));
    }

}

@Entity
public class MailResource extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Mail mail;

    private String name;
    private MailResourceType type;
    private byte[] content;
}
```

And when I saved them:

```
Mail mail = new Mail("asdasd@asd.com", "Hi!", "...");
mail.addResource("image", MailResourceType.INLINE, someBytes);
mail.addResource("documentation.pdf", MailResourceType.ATTACHMENT, someOtherBytes);
mailRepository.save(mail);
```

Three inserts were executed:

```
INSERT INTO MAIL (ID, BODY, QUEUED, RECEIVER, SENT, SUBJECT) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
INSERT INTO MAILRESOURCE (ID, CONTENT, NAME, TYPE, MAIL_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
INSERT INTO MAILRESOURCE (ID, CONTENT, NAME, TYPE, MAIL_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Then I thought it would be better using only a OneToMany relation. No need to save which Mail is in every MailResource:

```
@Entity
public class Mail extends BaseEntity {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "mail_id")
    private List<MailResource> resource;

    ...

    public void addResource(String name, MailResourceType type, byte[] content) {
        resource.add(new MailResource(name, type, content));
    }

}

@Entity
public class MailResource extends BaseEntity {
    private String name;
    private MailResourceType type;
    private byte[] content;
}
```

Generated tables are exactly the same (MailResource has a FK to Mail). The problem is the executed SQL:

```
INSERT INTO MAIL (ID, BODY, QUEUED, RECEIVER, SENT, SUBJECT) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
INSERT INTO MAILRESOURCE (ID, CONTENT, NAME, TYPE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
INSERT INTO MAILRESOURCE (ID, CONTENT, NAME, TYPE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
UPDATE MAILRESOURCE SET mail_id = ? WHERE (ID = ?)
UPDATE MAILRESOURCE SET mail_id = ? WHERE (ID = ?)
```

Why this two updates? I'm using EclipseLink, will this behaviour be the same using another JPA provider as Hibernate? Which solution is better?

**UPDATE:** 
 - If I don't use @JoinColumn EclipseLink creates three tables: MAIL, MAILRESOURCE and MAIL_MAILRESOURCE. I think this is perfectly logic. But with @JoinColumn it has information enough for creating only two tables and, in my opinion, do only inserts, with no updates.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a @JoinColumn in a OneToMany you are defining a "unidirectional" one to many, which is a new type of mapping added in JPA 2.0, this was not supported in JPA 1.0.

This is normally not the best way to define a OneToMany, a normal OneToMany is defined using a mappedBy and having a ManyToOne in the target object.  Otherwise the target object has no knowledge of this foreign key, and thus the separate update for it.

You can also use a JoinTable instead of the JoinColumn (this is the default for OneToMany), and then there is no foreign key in the target to worry about.

There is also a fourth option.  You could mark the MailResource as an Embeddable instead of Entity and use an ElementCollection.

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany

Comment: But I want only two tables being generated (Mail and MailResource). If I use an ElementCollection of Embeddable I would get three, woudn't I?

Answer (score 0):

Mapped by defines owning side of the relation ship so for JPA it gives better way to handle associations. Join Column only defines the relationship column. Since JPA is completely reflection based framework I could think of the optimization done for Mapped by since it is easy find owning side this way.

Comment: Are you suggesting to use the mappedBy attribute of OneToMany instead of JoinColumn annotation?